# YII - Extension property must be set error

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am new to YII. I have creates simple modules through gii and it is working fine for me.

However, now when I am creating new module manually (Copied view / model and controller files of existing module ) and when i am making change in one action function in controller file, it giving me error that  :

> ERROR TEXT : Extension property must be set.

What I am doing is

> In Newscontroller.php (Which I am using as reference )

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
            Yii::app()->user->setState(Yii::app()->params['newsajaxImageVar'], null);
            $model = new News('search'); 
}
```

> HomeController.php (Which i am creating )

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
            Yii::app()->user->setState(Yii::app()->params['homesajaxImageVar'], null);
            $model = new Home('search');   // On this line, it is giving me error for Extension property must be set.
}
```

Did anyone face same issue before ? 
Thanks

Comment: Alright , this is working now, It was rules missing to define related to home in config / main.php file

Comment: Consider posting an answer explaining why it didn't work and how did you fix it

Comment: Please post the answer for future reference and other users.

Comment: Yeah,I have posted it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was because :

There are some params I have defined in Home view file and it was not there in main.php which should be mentioned there and that is reason when you creating $model = new home('search'), it gives error of extension.

So, I have added it and now it is working fine for me.

Thanks.